# Time Complexity Analysis of nested loops

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory, analysis

I am trying to calculate the runtime complexity of the following algorithm:
[image]

So far I have noticed, that for the first n/2 iterations of the outer while loop, the inner while loop iterates exactly 1 time (technically for the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop does not execute any iteration, but this should not matter for asymptotic runtime analysis). For the next n/4 iterations of the outer loop, the inner loop has 2 iterations, and so on.
From this observation I have derived the following sum:
[image]

For big n, the first two (negative) terms in the sum would go to 0, which would leave us with the simplified form of 2n, which then would mean the algorithm has is in O(n).

**My question**: Is there an easier way or trick to analyze this algorithm? For this solution, I had to use wolframalpha.com to simplify the sum.
For context, this is a question from an old university exam I am solving as preparation for my exams, which do not allow any help but a basic calculator.

Comment: The left side of your equation is only summing n/2 over and over again - the right side does something different. (Unless the second 4 should have been a 3)

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, I pasted the wrong screenshot